# Create vertical tabbar for ipad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

Today I tried to implement a vertical tabbar for iPad. I checked a lot of questions on Stackoverflow and other sites but couldn't find the appropriate answer. Here are what I found:

- https://github.com/futuresimple/FSVerticalTabBarController
- https://github.com/nst/SEVerticalTabBar
- https://github.com/NOUSguide/NGTabBarController

In my opinion, the third component is great. However, I guess I'll have to customize a lot before I can use to create this following UI:

[image]

So do you know any components/libraries that match my UI? It would be great if anyone can suggest me a correct one. Thanks.

Comment: Please share your code i have same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [FSVerticalTabBarController](https://github.com/futuresimple/FSVerticalTabBarController). I have used it and it is easy to modify...

Comment: Yep, finally I used this one. It's easy to customize.

Comment: How to use in swift?

Answer (score 1):

- You can try this component [IIViewDeckController](https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck). Its very light weight.
- Usually it will be used for Stackview, left Menu kind of UI.
- But you can do a small trick like below to achieve your design above.

  Steps:

  - The component have left, right, top, bottom and **center** stack of controllers.
  - Use a UITableView on your LeftViewController to design your above UI.
  - Each index will act as a container of OneViewController.
  - Clicking one cell of your tableview will place the appropriate ViewController in the **center** controller of IIViewDeckViewController.

Its very easy, I guess you will like it. Just take some time to go through their examples.
Hope it will be useful

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I saw and checked the aforementioned component but it seems not to be easy to customize. Additionally, my UI design doesn't have slide effect (the menu hides when selecting a cell). However, thanks and I vote up for you.

Answer (score 0):

I translated  futuresimple/FSVerticalTabBarController into Swift 5.

My repo is https://github.com/coyingcat/VerticalTabBar

---

Apple's doc **Implementing a Container View Controller** is great also

Comment: how to add this in my project ??

Comment: Copy the code, use like the demo.  No cocoapods etc. Any feature needed, please issue me